# connect to Gyro sensor

Tags: python, sockets, gyroscope

```
`import socket
 HOST = '......'    # The remote host
 PORT = .....              # The same port as used by the server
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect((HOST, PORT))

 data = s.recv(1934)
 s.close()
 print data`
```

i am sorry if it is stupid question but if i solve my problem i am too much ahead. i have a gyro sensor (box) that connect to my laptop with Lan. i only know the ip of this gyro (no idea about port). i want to connect to it with Python and take data. BTW as manufacturer told me i should define a alternative configuration (different ip in IPV4 for connection.it means ip in IPV4 should be different from Gyro). i try all codes in internet but as i understood i dont need to defined server because gyro automatically send data and i need only client.if you have any idea or code, it will be a good help for me.
thanks in advance

Comment: You should really write more details, currently it is very confusing. Either read the manual more carefully, or if it isn't more detailed than this, return it back to whereever you bought it and buy another brand. Mentioning the brand and the model might also be helpful.

Comment: the thing is that it has its own software but i should untegrate more tools myself. i wrote some codes but it stuck and does not work .and main problem is with recv(). i will put my code

Comment: i know main problem is with recv(because when i remove it program run but i think only connect to gyro. when i add this part, it stuck.)

Comment: recv is in blocking mode initially. If there is no data, then it blocks.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html and search for setblocking.Maybe that Gyro wants a command first? Or maybe it only returns data if you shake it a bit?

Comment: i adjusted Gyro to give data each second. Gyro software itself each 10 second record a new row as ascii file. but i dont know why it does not send to my laptop with this code. it is easy to have data as txt file but i want to see it in my console with my program.not Gyro software.

Comment: Maybe run wireshark to see what's really going on in the network.

Comment: this Wireshark is perfect.i try to figure out whats going on with this local network.Vielen Dank Hilman.